# Content beneath Webbrowser

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm making an Windows Phone 8 Application where I would like to have a page filling webbrowser, but when you scroll to the bottom of the webbrowser extra content (buttons/text/images) is beneath it. The webbrowser has various heights depending on the website.

[image: example1]

and when you scroll down to the end of the webbrowser

[image: example2]

Any help will be appreciated!

Currently I have to following:
This code places the image on the bottom of the screen, but not beneath the webbrowser.

```
<Grid 
    x:Name="ContentPanel" 
    Grid.Row="1" 
    Margin="12,0,12,0">

    <phone:WebBrowser 
        x:Name="webView" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        IsScriptEnabled="True" 
        Margin="-13,-26,-13,0"/>

    <Image
        Height="100"
        Width="Auto" 
        Source="Assets/ContentPage/item_follow_icon.png"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to make the browser semi-transparent?  Or make the image the displayed web page's background?

Comment: I want a full screen browser and if you scroll to the bottom of the webpage, extra content apears. I will provider the question With images to explain.

Comment: Updated my question! Hope it makes things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a Stackpanel.

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel orientation="Vertical">
        <phone:WebBrowser 
            x:Name="webView" 
            IsScriptEnabled="True" 
            Margin="-13,-26,-13,0"/>

        <Image
            Height="100"
            Width="Auto" 
            Source="Assets/ContentPage/item_follow_icon.png"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Try this without the `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"`

Comment: Improved the Answer, hope this will help

Comment: The only problem with `StackPanel` here is that it won't expand to fill the size of its container.  So there's no way to auto-size the browser.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to define rows in your Grid:

```
<Grid ... >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <phone:WebBrowser Grid.Row="0" ... />

    <Image Grid.Row="1" ... />
</Grid>
```

Putting `Height="Auto"` in the second row and `Height="*"` in the second means that your image will get sized first, and then the browser will fill up the remaining space.